# Java: File Renaming Detection

Tags: java, file, rename, nio, detect

Is there a way to detect file renaming using Java? (NIO's WatchService API or any other)
From what I've seen when renaming a file two separate events occur - ENTRY_DELETE and then ENTRY_CREATE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [jpathwatch](http://jpathwatch.wordpress.com). In addition to the standard watch event kinds specified in Java 7 (`ENTRY_CREATE, ENTRY_DELETE, ENTRY_MODIFY`) it also has additional events called `ENTRY_RENAME_FROM` and `ENTRY_RENAME_TO` which will fire when a file is renamed. Note that this depends on whether the underlying operating system supports file renaming events or not.

Answer (score 4):

Detecting renaming of files can not be done portably. Because, surprising as it may seem, the idea that a file HAS-A name is not portable. Most Unix file systems allow a file to have any number of ASSOCIATED names (including zero names). In the Unix (POSIX) world, renaming means adding a new name and then removing the original name.

Answer (score 2):

I think the [jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/) would be useful in your case.